# Get username of Basic Auth in APIM

Tags: wso2, basic-authentication, wso2-api-manager

Is there a way we can retrieve the username of the user that is in Basic Auth? Get the username of the basic auth and save inside a property to use it in API Manager Logic

Thanks

I have done it before with MI and WWSecurity but not with APIM and Basic auth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you cannot achieve this via a simple mediation sequence as we record the username field inside the authenticationContext object.

However with a [customer handler](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/reference/customize-product/extending-api-manager/extending-gateway/writing-custom-handlers/#introducing-handlers) or a custom [class mediator](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/references/mediators/class-Mediator/), you can access this object from java. You can get this object from the synapse context via `(AuthenticationContext) synCtx.getProperty("__API_AUTH_CONTEXT")`. [Here](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt/blob/v9.20.74/components/apimgt/org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/apimgt/gateway/handlers/throttling/ThrottleHandler.java#L605) is an example of this object returned in the throttle handler. You can use the [getter](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt/blob/v9.20.74/components/apimgt/org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/apimgt/gateway/handlers/security/AuthenticationContext.java#L106) getUsername() to get the username of the requester and set this as a syapse property.